# uTidylib segmentation fault

Tags: python, macos, segmentation-fault, tidy

uTidylib is crashing and giving me a segmentation fault every time I try to use it.

Here's some info about the crash:

```
Process:         Python [432]
Path:            /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
Identifier:      Python
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  bash [429]

PlugIn Path:       /usr/local/lib/libtidy.so
PlugIn Identifier: libtidy.so
PlugIn Version:    ??? (???)

Date/Time:       2010-10-31 14:45:22.069 -0600
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.6.4 (10F569)
Report Version:  6

Interval Since Last Report:          78084 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           6
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   5

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000000008a8aa0
```

Any ideas?

Is there any other python tidy wrapper?

Comment: what did you want to use it for? only xml/html parsing?

Comment: I am using BeautifulSoup and I need to clean the html first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[pyTidyLib](http://countergram.com/open-source/pytidylib/docs/index.html) , the utidylib is too old (last time updated 2004 )